# Does python have an arguments processing order well defined?

Tags: python

I am wondering if I have the function

```
def f(*args):
    print(*args)
```

if I run it like this, do I have any guarantee of the order of processing arguments? I know c++ does not guarantee an order like this.

```
>>> d = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8}
>>> f(d.pop(1), d.pop(3), {k:v for k, v in d.items()})
2 4 {5: 6, 7: 8}
```

If the arguments were processed out of order, we may get

```
2 4 {1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8}
```

or

```
2 4 {1:2, 5:6, 7:8}
```

or

```
2 4 {3:4, 5:6, 7:8}
```

It seems to work, however I am not sure if this is just an effect of cPython or standard of python, or neither. I cannot seem to find the documentation on this.

Comment: @MooingRawr I think that is actually not relevant to this question, although, it is a poor choice for an example. A list would have been better.

Comment: the order of *args is the order in which the caller puts them. Programming would be rather difficult if it weren't. The order of keyword arguments, i.e. arguments passed in the syntax name=value used to be undefined, however, starting with python 3.6 these also remember the order in which they are passed.

Comment: Guys, the question is asking about the order of evaluation of the arguments at function-call time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*args` will come through in the order you sent them, this is guaranteed by the language.  Function arguments are also [evaluated left to right](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order), this is guaranteed by the language.  Python has to make *some* choice about this, otherwise the evaluation of one argument could mutate another argument and result in unspecified behaviour.

You can rely on the behaviour you've described in the question:

```
2 4 {5: 6, 7: 8}
```

However, note the result below is also a valid Python output.  Though you're unlikely to see it in CPython due to some implementation detail about `dict` and `int`.

```
2 4 {7: 8, 5: 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C and C++, [Python guarantees that function arguments are evaluated left to right](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order). You can be sure the `pop` calls will run before the dict comprehension.

> #### 6.15. Evaluation order
>
> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side
>   is evaluated before the left-hand side.
>
> In the following lines, expressions will be evaluated in the
>   arithmetic order of their suffixes:
>
> ```
> expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4
> (expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4)
> {expr1: expr2, expr3: expr4}
> expr1 + expr2 * (expr3 - expr4)
> expr1(expr2, expr3, *expr4, **expr5)
> expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2
> ```